# How to call DISM command in WIX 3.7

Tags: wix, custom-action, dism

I want to execute the below lines of code through WIX and here is the code where am able to do it through the command prompt:

dism.exe /online /enable-feature:NetFx3 /quiet /norestart -----> To enable

dism /online /get-featureinfo:netfx3 ------> To verify the value

Answer (score 0):

If all that you want to do using Wix is to launch executables, Wix/windows installer  provides multiple ways to do that.

I generally prefer using Quite Execution custom actions provided by the Wix toolset. Reason being, it allows me to launch executables without displaying any console windows, which otherwise would have required me to write custom action code.

Take a look at :

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/qtexec.html

The examples in the above URL are sufficient enough to help you get started.

In order to use QtExec (Quite execution custom actions), you must include a reference to the WixUtilExtension when building your MSI. To do this, add the command line argument -ext WixUtilExtension.dll when calling Light.exe.